# Class binding based on variable value not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to define a class dynamically to a TD like this.

```
 <td [className]="'myProject.OverallProjectStatus'" >{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>
```

But on rendering it shows

```
 <td class="myProject.OverallProjectStatus" >Green</td>
```

I was expecting the value behind that variable Green their like this

```
 <td class="Green" >Green</td>
```

How can I achieve that? I'm working in Angular 9

Comment: Did you try `<td [className]="myProject.OverallProjectStatus" >{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `'`, you only need the `"`.

```html
<td [className]="myProject.OverallProjectStatus" >{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller variables are referred in property bindings either by double quotes or single quotes. The following refer to a valid member variable in the controller.

Refers to member variables

```html
<td [className]="myProject.OverallProjectStatus">{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>

OR

<td [className]='myProject.OverallProjectStatus'>{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>
```

If you were to mix them up and enclose the inner variable name in another set of quotes, then the variable would be considered as string literal.

Refers to string literal

```html
<td [className]="'myProject.OverallProjectStatus'">{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>

OR

<td [className]='"myProject.OverallProjectStatus"'>{{myProject.OverallProjectStatus}}</td>
```

Although the common convention to denote member variable and string literal are `"myProject.OverallProjectStatus"` and `"'myProject.OverallProjectStatus'"` respectively.